# When I cancel a unit test run does the currently running test complete?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, nunit, vs-unit-testing-framework

Can anyone tell me: When I press Cancel in the Test Explorer window during a unit test run, is execution simply terminated there and then, or will the currently running test actually run to completion? (Or does it depend which test adapter is being used?)
I'm using VS2012. Some solutions use the Microsoft test adapter, some use NUnit (if it makes a difference).

Comment: Have you tried testing it yourself? create a test with a long running task. place an assert of some kind after the delay. Run the test and cancel before the predefined delay and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two part answer...

1. It **does** depend on the particular adapter. The Test Explorer calls the adapter's `ITestExecutor.Cancel()` method and what happens after that point depends on the adapter.
2. With respect to NUnit...

   If you are using the NUnit 3 VS adapter and running tests using the NUnit 3 framework, the test is cancelled immediately by aborting the thread(s) that is(are) executing the current test(tests). [Parens because you may be running multiple tests in parallel with NUnit 3.] No teardowns are run.

   If you are using the NUnit [V2] VS adapter, the thread is killed immediately and all execution stops. No teardowns are run.

Comment: Thanks for that, although I can't quite work out the difference between NUnit 2 and NUnit 3 - in both cases you seem to be saying that the test(s) is(are) terminated immediately and no teardown is run. Also, for completeness, do you happen to know what the MS adapter's behaviour is?

Comment: Between 2 and 3, purely an implementation difference, but since 3 is much more complex, with multiple threads, there's obviously more that could go wrong. I'm an NUnit guy, but since the MSTest adapter is written by the same company that creates Visual Studio, I would tend to trust their docs. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> is execution simply terminated there and then, or will the currently running test actually run to completion?

Found documentations that states

> This stops the test run at its current location. **The test being run is completed, but no additional tests are run**. Results from any already completed tests in the current test run are retained. The status of the test that was running when you clicked Stop changes to Aborted. The status of tests that have not yet completed changes from Pending to Not Executed.

*Emphasis mine*

So it appears what ever test is currently running when you cancel will go to completion if possible, but no further tests will be run.

Note that the above is quote for MSTest. I am uncertain about other test runners.

Comment: I think you are probably looking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182471(v=vs.80).aspx. This refers to VS2005 and says "While a test run is underway, click Stop on the Test Results window toolbar", which is quite different from VS2012 which involves clicking Cancel in the Test Explorer window, so I suspect it's not useful.